# Pass traffic from remote access to site to site tunnel

Tags: cisco, vpn, firewall, ipsec

I have situation where remote access ipsec client have to connect to ASA firewall to send and receive traffic using site to site tunnel on the same ASA, in the logs I am seeing packets dropped as it is sourced and destinated to the same interface.
Did any one ever tried such setup? Did it work? I see it is logical and possible

Comment: Are you saying you want client VPN users to be able to pass traffic through a site-to-site VPN terminated on the same ASA?

Comment: If so, yes that's easy and very common. If you can edit your question to include a sanitized copy of your running configuration along with the details of which tunnel you want to talk to which other tunnel, we can help you script out the changes.

Comment: We are still waiting for you to provide more information in order to accurately answer your questions.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to permit flows of traffic, that coming in on an interface and  to be routed back out the same interface

```
same-security permit intra-interface
```

it's called hairpinning: https://community.cisco.com/t5/security-documents/hairpin-u-turn-traffic-off-an-interface-on-an-asa-running-8-3-or/ta-p/3129668

Comment: While that is somewhat correct, and you could POTENTIALLY need hairpinning (depending on whether or not there are same or separate interfaces for client VPN and site-to-site VPN), there are other things to account for such as interesting traffic ACL modifications, NAT (or NAT exemption) modifications, possible routing statement modifications, etc.

Comment: yes and you should have ASA in place to

Comment: I'm confused. This post is about having an ASA and using it for VPNs. What do you mean by "have ASA in place to"?

Comment: well, of course he should account for other things to, his question is about traffic coming and leaving the same interface and it's hair pinning.

Comment: That's fair in this case but, it's up to the people here that offer help (by answering questions) to look beyond the obvious question and make sure that the OP has everything they need that may not have been thought of, since they're usually asking a question because they don't already know how to do it.  I feel your answer is too black and white. If the user didn't account for everything I previously mentioned, simply enabling hairpinning won't change the final result.

Comment: Totally agree with you.